# change color of same div on ng-mouseover and ng-mouseout events angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have div tag, on-mouseover i wish to change existing div color to other and vice versa for on-mouseout.

```
<div class="btn col-lg-3" style="color:white;" ng-mouseover="" ng-mouseout="" ng-class="">
    <strong>ABOUT</strong>
</div>
```

How can i achieve this using angularjs? can anyone help me

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5rAyJ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <div class="btn col-lg-3" style="color:white;" ng-class="{'call-name':hovering}"  ng-mouseenter="hovering=true"
ng-mouseleave="hovering=false">
     <strong>ABOUT</strong>
  </div>
```